# Rails - Highcharts on Heroku - Getting 'ReferenceError: Highcharts is not defined'

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, heroku, highcharts

I'm using highcharts to plot some graphs. It works just fine locally, but when deployed to heroku, I get this javascript error saying that Highcharts is not defined. I though maybe the javascript file isn't precompiled, but I checked the heroku logs and I see that it does get precompiled. I also go to **myapp.herokuapp.com/assets/highcharts.js** and I find it there.
So I'm not sure what the problem is.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

--- This is the html of the page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="/assets/application-eb12a5437181ffb065f7793b96f720c9.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="/assets/application-b5b4fd7bed721cbc4cc70b5a8c8654e9.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
....
<div id="container2" style="min-width: 400px; height: 100%; margin: 0 auto"></div><br><br />

<script>
$(function () {
    var chart2;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        chart2 = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
            renderTo: 'container2',
            type: 'bar',
            height: 450
         },
        title: {
            text: 'Questions'
        },
         subtitle: {
            text: 'number of students with answer'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ["Part3 00:03:31", "Part4 00:03:41", "Part5 00:06:17"],
            labels:{
            useHTML: true}

        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            allowDecimals: false,
            title: {
                text: 'Number of Students'
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false,
            layout: 'vertical',
            backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
            align: 'left',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            x: 100,
            y: 70,
            floating: true,
            shadow: true
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                return ''+
                    this.series.name+': '+ this.y +' student(s)<br>'+question(this.point.x, this.series.name);
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                pointPadding: 0.2,
                borderWidth: 0
            }
        },

        series: [{"name":"Answer 1","data":[11,7,6]},{"name":"Answer 2","data":[4,6,2]},{"name":"Answer 3","data":[5,7,6]},{"name":"Answer 4","data":[0,0,6]}]
    });
```

Comment: Can you show us the html source of the page?

Comment: Are you including `highcharts.js` in your `application.js` file?

Comment: Yes I have: //= require highcharts and //= require highcharts/modules/exporting .. I'm using the highcharts-rails gem.

Comment: Ok, so I removed the gem, and just manually added the javascript files, and included them in my view and it worked.. not sure why I had to do that though.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest using this gem: https://github.com/market76/lazy_high_charts

It makes using High Charts in a Rails application much easier.  You can export graph images server side with PhantomJS as well.